# rawsocket sendto() some of the packet are dropped and not seen in the network

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, raw-sockets

```
socketFd_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, protoType);    
sentBytes = sendto(socketFd_, buf, len, 0, 
                  (struct sockaddr   *)&sa,sizeof(structsockaddr_in));
protoType = GRE
```

I am sending the 1000 packets in the network.
If my tx packet rate is 40, i am able to see all the packet in wireshark.
however when i will try to send at the rate of 100 some of the packet(3-4) will not reach in the network however sendto did not return any error.
i know sendto will just put the txpacket into the queue and will not guarantee the delivery of packet in the network however from where i can get the drop packet statistics and reason for packet drop in the kernel.
i have tried increasing the txqueuelen of interface to 65000 but it did not helped.
how can i debug this issue?.

Comment: i tried to check for send buffer size using :

getsockopt(socketFd_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sendBuffSize, &buffLen);

it shows a large value sendBuffSize = 124928,

and i observed whenever my pending buffer size after system call sendto() reached 2040 it will drop the packet(sendto is returning successfully here), i am checking the outstanding sendto buffer size using 
ioctl(socketFd_, SIOCOUTQ, &outstandingBytes);
my question is why sendto is not returning any error? is it because sendBuffSize is larger then outstandingBytes?
can anyone help me in debugging this issue?.
Thanks

Comment: one more test scenario after sendto if i will wait for outstatndingBytes to reach zero before calling sendto again there will not be any packet loss in the system

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that sendto will just put the txpacket in the queue and not guarantee delivery.

From the iEEE documentation on sendto:

*Successful completion of a call to sendto() does not guarantee delivery of the message. A return value of -1 indicates only locally-detected errors.*

You have to perform some of your own throttling via ioctl() and getsockopt() as you are almost doing.  I don't think you can expect the network stack to do it all for you.

Something like:

```
sendMsgThrottled( msg Msg ) {
    ioctl(socketFd_, SIOCOUTQ, &outstandingBytes);  
    if ( outStandingBytes < limit )
          sendto(socketFd_, ..)
    else
          queueMsg();  /* Or delay */
}
```

I would test this with by having the send and receiver on the same machine, packet loss can come from other places besides the network layer of the operating system.

Comment: calling a system call ioctl after every sendto will be a performance hit,however my concern here is why packet are being dropped when oustandingBytes reaches 2040, how can i increase this limit.  
my send buffer size is 124928 i get this value using getsockopt() SO_SNDBUF option.

Comment: what is the size of the packets you are sending? And what is the rate is that 40/sec ? ioctl() is usually not a a big performance hit.

Comment: size of the packet will be aronnd 326 Bytes, i am observing this issue when i will send at the rate of 400 packet /sec,  
From the wireshark i have seen with in 150 microsecond i will inject 10 packet into the network.(kind of small burst, i will call a 1 ms timer which periodically inject burst of packet as per rate)

Comment: Do you have the Naggle algorithm turned off?

Comment: if i am not wrong nagles's algoritham is only for tcp, for my case protocol above IP will be either a GRE or UDP .

Comment: yes, you are correct, Naggle is for TCP only, my apologies.  UDP is not guaranteed to be delivered.  Do you have a requirement of zero packet loss?

Comment: yes, at least it should go out of Linux kernel and appear in network